# GPS provider not available

Tags: gps, android-manifest

I have followed http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

to implement the GPS Apps ( Google Maps)

I have installed Google API 8 , installed the Console and type geo fix, register the google MAP API Key.

But I don't why my application has been stopped unexpectedly

Here is my manifest.xml

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".ShowMap" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

</application>
```

Comment: i too get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have add a library to the manifest file.

```
 <uses-library android:required="true"
 android:name="com.google.android.maps"></uses-library>
```

Add this line as application child in your manifest file. Then you might not get the error.
Hope this works.